# c++ program return "0 0" instead of returning prime numbers. Why does it not get the correct output from the "prime" function?

Tags: c++, primes, iostream, dynamic-arrays

My function "prime" takes a dynamic array and returns a dynamically allotted array consisting of only prime numbers. But when it is returned to main, it gives the wrong output and print

**Output:**

```
0 0
```

**Expected Output:**

```
2 3
```

**My Code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
const int capacity = 10000;
int * prime(int numbers[capacity])
{
    int *primeArray;
    primeArray = new int[capacity];
    int lenghtOfArray=sizeof(primeArray)/sizeof(int); 
    int counter = 0;
    for(int index=0;index<lenghtOfArray;index++){
    // 0 and 1 are not prime numbers
    if (numbers[index] == 0 || numbers[index] == 1) {
        continue;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 2; i <= numbers[index] / 2; ++i) {
            if (numbers[index] % i == 0) {
                primeArray[counter] = numbers[index];
                counter = counter + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    }
    return primeArray;
}


main()
{
    int *mynumbers;
    mynumbers = new int[capacity];
    mynumbers[0] = 1;
    mynumbers[1] = 2;
    mynumbers[2] = 3;
    mynumbers[3] = 4;
    mynumbers[4] = 5;
    mynumbers[5] = 6;
    int* myprime = prime(mynumbers);
    cout << myprime[0] << " " << myprime[1];
}
```

What went wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    int lenghtOfArray=sizeof(primeArray)/sizeof(int);
```

is an wrong way to get the length of dynamically allocated array.

`sizeof(primeArray)` is not the allocated size but the size of pointer.

You already have the number of elements of the array, so use that to get the length of the array:

```
    int lenghtOfArray=capacity;
```

But this doesn't make your code correct because now your code will use indeterminate values of uninitialized elements of `int` array. What you have to do is to pass the number of valid elements to the function.

Points to change:

```
// add argument to pass the number of data
// int * prime(int numbers[capacity])
int * prime(int numbers[capacity], int num_numbers)
{
    int *primeArray;
    primeArray = new int[capacity];
    // use the passed number
    // int lenghtOfArray=sizeof(primeArray)/sizeof(int); 
    int lenghtOfArray=num_numbers;
```

```
    // pass the number of data
    // int* myprime = prime(mynumbers);
    int* myprime = prime(mynumbers, 6);
    cout << myprime[0] << " " << myprime[1];
}
```

Another point is that your code is storing numbers that are not primes instead of prime numbers.

Instead of this

```
        for (int i = 2; i <= numbers[index] / 2; ++i) {
            if (numbers[index] % i == 0) {
                primeArray[counter] = numbers[index];
                counter = counter + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
```

you should use this

```
        // add the number for now
        primeArray[counter] = numbers[index];
        counter = counter + 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= numbers[index] / 2; ++i) {
            if (numbers[index] % i == 0) {
                // it is not actually a prime, rollback
                counter = counter - 1;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Another problem is that the function does not output how many primes it actually found. In this particular example, there are 2 primes.  But in general, there will not always be exactly 2. So the function should output the number of primes it actually stored in the returned array, so that the caller knows how many numbers it can safely read from the array.  Also, `main()` is leaking the allocated array.  A `std::vector` would be a better choice to solve both issues.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, `std::vector` should be used instead of arrays.

Comment: You should store 2 into the first slot of the array and start the loop at 3, incrementing by 2.  This will cut the number of iterations in half.